# Second Order Linear Homogeneous Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to learn recurrence relations and I want to find the general formula of second-order linear homogeneous relation

$a_n=6a_{n-1}-8a_{n-2}$ where $a_0=1; a_1=4.$

So I started with the characteristic equation and I got this:

$r^2-6r+8=0$

After finding roots I should find a general formula for this relation:

$a_n=\alpha(4^n)+\beta(2^n)$

after plugging given values, I have got an equation:

$a_n=4^n$, and it's incorrect. Can someone help me and explain where I have a mistake? Also is it possible to solve this type of problem with the plug and chug method?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I. do not see anything wrong. Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging $n=0,1$ in the general solution $a_n = \alpha 4^n + \beta 2^n$ you get the linear system:

$$\begin{cases} \alpha + \beta = 1 \\ 4\alpha + 2\beta = 4\end{cases} \; ,$$

from which you obtain:

$$\alpha = 1,\ \beta = 0 \; .$$

Therefore your solution is correct... Why do you think it is not?

Comment: So I checked it a second time and guess it's correct, thanks for your answer. Can you tell me if is it possible to solve this type of relations with the plug and chug method?

Comment: More "plug and chug" than this? I mean, you just "plugged" the guess $a_n = \alpha 4^n + \beta 2^n$ in your initial conditions and, with mild manual effort, you "chugged" the correct values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$...  What more can you ask?

Comment: I mean there is method when you calculate $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ and then chug it in equation. After some steps some pattern is visible and you write general formula. I know this method only for first order homogeneous equations, not for this. Can I do this method here too?

Comment: Ah, ok, you mean what I usually call “guessing a formula by examples”… Of course you can use this technique also in the second order setting, but “guessing” the correct formula is quite more complicated than for first order equations.

Comment: Yes I tried I couldn't, I hope someone would teach me